# Does renaming column will set pre populated value to NULL?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I created a migration to rename column name `type` to `checkin_type`. Before renaming `type` column contains some value for old records. But with the migration after renaming column to `checkin_type`, value set `NULL` for all records.

I am confused that it is right or something wrong with migration. Idea is that while renaming column value of old saved records should not get changed.

Here is my migration

```
class RenameTypeToCheckinType < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    Lhm.change_table :checkins do |m|
      m.ddl(sprintf("alter table %s CHANGE type checkin_type VARCHAR(100)", m.name))
    end
 end

def self.down
  Lhm.change_table :checkins do |m|
    m.ddl(sprintf("alter table %s CHANGE checkin_type type VARCHAR(100)", m.name))
  end
end
```

end

Comment: What is `Lhm`? What database are you using?

Comment: What type this column was before?

Comment: Column type was string as u can see `VARCHAR(100)` in migration